# can't send mail by gmail with PhpMailer

Tags: php, email, xampp, gmail, phpmailer

I'm tryng to send an email by phpmailer with a gmail account.
the pages are hosted in localhost xampp.
PHP Version 5.6.3

this is my code:

```
require_once 'Classes/class.phpmailer.php';
require 'Classes/class.smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
//$mail->IsSMTP(); // Use SMTP
$mail->Host        = "smtp.gmail.com"; // Sets SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug   = 2; // 2 to enable SMTP debug information
$mail->SMTPAuth    = TRUE; // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure  = "tls"; //Secure conection
$mail->Port        = 587; // set the SMTP port
$mail->Username    = 'myemail@gmail.com'; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password    = 'myPassword'; // SMTP account password
$mail->Priority    = 1; // Highest priority - Email priority (1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low)
$mail->Encoding    = '8bit';
$mail->Subject     = 'Test Email Using Gmail';
$mail->ContentType = 'text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n';
$mail->From        = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName    = 'GMail Test';
$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->AddAddress('mywifeemail@gmail.com');
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
$mail->Body    = "Hello";
   if(!$mail->Send())
      {
         echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
      }
      else
      {
         echo "Message sent!";
      }
```

in this way, the page response is "Message sent!", but i don't recive any mail. If i uncomment

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
```

this is the error that appears;

```
2015-11-21 17:08:04 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP q1sm4963515wjy.31 - gsmtp 2015-11-21 17:08:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2015-11-21 17:08:04 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [93.55.36.161] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 2015-11-21 17:08:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2015-11-21 17:08:04 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS 2015-11-21 17:08:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2015-11-21 17:08:05 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [93.55.36.161] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 2015-11-21 17:08:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2015-11-21 17:08:05 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 2015-11-21 17:08:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: cGFzcXVhbGUudHJpdGVsbGFAZ21haWwuY29t 2015-11-21 17:08:05 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 2015-11-21 17:08:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: bW9ycm83NGRvcm8= 2015-11-21 17:08:05 SERVER -> CLIENT: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 q1sm4963515wjy.31 - gsmtp 2015-11-21 17:08:05 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 q1sm4963515wjy.31 - gsmtp 2015-11-21 17:08:05 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2015-11-21 17:08:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2015-11-21 17:08:05 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection q1sm4963515wjy.31 - gsmtp 2015-11-21 17:08:05 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

i tryed several solutions, but it seems not working anyway....
any idea how to resolve??
thanks in advance

Comment: for gmail you have to give access to less secure apps. This can be the problem. visit this link https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: `$mail->Send()` returns `true`, that means PHPMailer has done it's work. Now it's upto Google to deliver the email. Technically your email will go through several servers and sometimes it takes quite a while, especially when you use an application to send mails. And sometimes due to some *technical reasons* your emails might end up in **spam folder**, so check your spam folder first. You can find more information here, [https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2935079?hl=en#ts=2935090](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2935079?hl=en#ts=2935090)

Comment: I gave a lower secure to google apps, and now it works fine. thank you!